# jQuery not working after executing once

Tags: javascript, jquery

As [you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/DdS7H/), my little jQuery script isn't working after running twice, and I'm getting a weird error. Do any of you happen to know what's going on/how to fix it? That would be fantastic if you did!

Thank you!

Connor

Comment: Note: the error shows up on 2 returns

Comment: @thenoviceoof Thank you - just fixed it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only binding the keypress event on the first `.focus` element. Once you remove it, it will no longer receive keypress events.

Change this line

```
$(".focus").keypress(function(event) {
```

To

```
$(".focus").live("keypress",function(event) {
```

jQuery `.live()` attaches a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

Also, you need to add this after the line <strike>above</strike> below to prevent unexpected behavior:

```
if (event.which == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();    < stop the enter keypress
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked flawlessly. Thank you - I'll mark it as correct once it allows me to!

Comment: Also, you might want to consider Ates's advice and just insert , `.before()`, the text to the `.active-live` element and not remove the `<input>` at all.

Comment: I'm definitely considering that. Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're removing the element for which you're adding the initial `keypress` event handler. A quick fix would be to take out the event handler into a function and reattach it to your newly added element:

```
function handleKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        var itemToAdd = $(".focus").val();
        if (itemToAdd != ""){
            $(this).remove();
            $(".active-li").append(itemToAdd);
            $("#wrapper ul").append("<li class='active'><input type='text' class='root focus' /></li>");
            $(".active-li").removeAttr("class");
            $(".active").removeClass("active").addClass("active-li");
            $(".focus").keypress(handleKeyPress).focus();
        }
    }
}

$(".focus").keypress(handleKeyPress);
```

But I must say, this looks like a very inefficient way to achieve what you're trying to do here... Think of an alternative solution where you don't have to remove your input element (just insert the new `<li>` before it).

Comment: Thank you Ates, I'll definitely consider that!